# What parameters does google closure compiler appspot use?

Tags: javascript, java, closures, google-closure-compiler, flags

I am using google's closure compiler to minimize my js files. When I use the website version [here](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) with the advanced options it works just fine, but when I downloaded their Java application, from [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app), and set the flag like this:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js /code/built.js --js_output_file compiledCode.js
```

Then some features of my program stops working. I guess it's not compatible with the ooptimization algorithm. So my question is, what flags should I use to replicate the optimization used on the appspot version?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web service does not enable the type-based optimizations by default. So to get the equivalent functionality:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
    --use_types_for_optimization=false
    --js /code/built.js --js_output_file compiledCode.js
```

The web service also assumes any undefined symbol is an external library. For this reason it is not recommended for production use.

Comment: I've noticed another problem with the downloaded version. It removes one folder of the urls from Ajax requests. First the url was: "/folder1/folder2/phpQuery.php" but it converts it to "/folder2/phpQuery.php"